# How to add serial number over a randomly generated resultset in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am stuck in a situation where I have to add a 'Serial No.' over a resultset in SQL. 
The scenario is like below:

MyTable is like,

[image]

Now, after using the following query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable  
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

I am getting output like this,

[image]

Now, I want an output like this,

[image]

Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS SlNo` gives me the serial number just same as my ID, which is not at serially ordered (and this is logically correct too).

Please help me out with some solutions. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
Pardon me for my mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, the following will work - it will order by the first column of the result. It still provides a random order.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS SlNo, * 
FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you Sire. It worked like a charm. I am accepting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by the first column

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID()), * 
FROM MyTable  
ORDER BY 1
```

Or you can make a subquery so you can order by column name

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID()) AS SLNo, * 
  FROM MyTable  
) TBL
ORDER BY SLNo
```